# Append div from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have append div with images tag in it without any problem.

What I am having problem right now is how to append div from right to left without affecting so much of my current code, with the same effects. Is it possible to this?

I have tried using `css` `float` attribute but no luck on it.

Here is the main loop for my code:

```
img = '<div id="deck1">'
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var rand = makeUniqueRandom();
    j = rand + 1;
    img +='<img id="img'+j+'" src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff&text='+j+'" />';           
}
img += '</div">'
$("#deck").append(img);
```

Demo link for my code:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/117/)

**UPDATE:**

What I wanted to do is append images from right to left.

For example:

**Current Result** is:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

**Expected Result** should be:

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Which can also be used for future implementations, which in my end will be adding a second line, thus making the output look like this, because I am planning to add line 10-18 in the 2nd line which will output this way:

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10

That is what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is what you are looking for

Comment: @BeNdErR look at my updated quesion.

Comment: are you looking for something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Jc2kJ/ ?

Comment: @BeNdErR, yes, and where we can use for future implementations, for example doing it in the next line.

Comment: sorry but I don't get what you mean with ' and where we can use for future implementations, for example doing it in the next line'

Comment: So you want the numbers to be 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 when you click reorder?

Comment: @lzekid Yes with that order.

Comment: @BeNdErR look at my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns the string, sorted from right to left, that you will append to the DOM, and call it whenever you need it passing the array that needs to be sorted

**JS**

```
function appendRightLeft(arr){
    var str = "";
    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        str = arr[x] + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/Jc2kJ/3/

Here I used array as parameter for simplicity, but you can edit the code to simply create `img` tags using a start and an end index, for example

```
function myFunc(start, end){
    for(var x = start, x < end; x++){
        //--- create your string here
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont what to change my code right now, how can this be applied to my current code.